# jquery detect class and add css to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an example of a scenario I have got:

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <a class="show-project" href="#">
    <!-- some content here -->
  </a>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <!-- full height container with scroll -->
  </div>
</div>
```

When link is clicked, additional class is added to "scrollable **move-left**".
I would like to detect when it is added and replace css "overflow-y: auto;" with "overflow-y: hidden;"

I am trying to achieve this with:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#portfolio .show-project").click(function(){
      if ($("#portfolio .scrollable").hasClass("move-left")) {
        $("#portfolio").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
      } else {
        $("#portfolio").css("overflow-y", "auto");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Could you advice me how to fix this please?
Very appreciated!

Comment: For detect if there are changes with any classes, attributes, properties etc. the best plugin is https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-watch. I use it in many my projects. Works perfect and easy to use

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) in order to toggle the class on the element and change the `overflow-y` attribute accordingly.

Ref:

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in
>   the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence
>   or the value of the state argument.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#portfolio .show-project").click(function () {
        $("#portfolio .scrollable").toggleClass('move-left');
        var overflow;
        ($("#portfolio .scrollable").hasClass("move-left")) ? overflow = 'hidden' : overflow = 'auto';
        $("#portfolio").css("overflow-y", overflow);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/n0d5jxe8/

Comment: Thank you Irvin for you example - it works. It works with html example I posted. Would you be able to advice on how to make it work in a next example please.

Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bmkjvz5v/2/

At the moment all of the "scrollable" containers are getting "move-left" class. Is there a way to detect if "move-left" was added or removed and depending on this "#portfolio" will have overflow-y: hidden or auto? There is already JavaScript in place that is adding / removing "move-left"
Maybe .click is not needed for this to work?